# Is it possible to see real-time updates for a custom dimension?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a custom dimension that I am trying to set in Google analytics.  It hasn't worked yet and I am looking for a way to debug it.  Is there a way to see if my dimension is being received by analytics real time?

The only reports I can find only show yesterday stats.

Comment: How did you achieve custom dimension in real time report @BrandenB171 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delay in reporting

There is delay in custom dimension processing.

### Console debugger

Use some debugger.

**Google Analytics debugger:** https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

OR **Charles Web Debugging Proxy**: http://www.charlesproxy.com/

OR **Live HTTP headers** : https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/

OR **Omnibug**: http://omnibug.rosssimpson.com/chrome.html

### What to check:

Check for URL parameter cd## where ## represents your Custom Dimensions number. If this is setted, be sure that Google Analytics will process this variable.

Check either, that your property has setted Custom Dimensions and they have right scope. HIT, SESSION and USER will work for all non product related metrics and dimensions. PRODUCT scope can be used only with Enhanced Ecommerce.

Comment: Is the delay just a couple minutes or is it a whole day?

Comment: It is usually a few hours. It depends on traffic. It could be in range 4 - 24 hours.